# Maven deployed third party jar does not contain class files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I uploaded a file to my company's inhouse repository using [deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).  This seemed to be successful and I then included the dependency in the POM of my project.  However, when it downloads the JAR from our maven repository I look in it in eclipse and it does not have any class files, although it does have the html doc files.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to have the compiled class files?

Comment: Maven just deploys what you hand it. Are you sure that the jar file was contentful when you passed it to deploy:deploy-file?

Comment: @bmargulies Yeah, turns out the JAR I deployed only had source and documenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JAR I deployed did not have the class files in it.  Uploaded the correct JAR and updated my projects and the problem was solved.